# Indefinite Article Before A Comma

Tags: grammar

What if the break is a comma, and so not parenthetical. As in "..while making an, at best, fitful transition from burnout to working class hero" does the pronunciation rule still hold?

Comment: "..while making, at best, a fitful transition..."

Comment: @MichaelHarvey If you treat "at best" as parenthetical the indefinite article should be 'a' as without the parenthesis the article relates to 'fitful'. The pronunciation problem is solved by pausing after 'a' to give "a <pause> at best <pause> fitful transition"

Comment: thanks, I'm still wrestling with it but leaning toward 'an' .. though I like Anton's answer below. I wonder if his last name is really Chigurh?

Answer (score 1):

I feel that “at best fitful” is an adjectival phrase in which “fitful” is qualified as the best end of a spectrum of adjectives that might be applied to “transition”. From that viewpoint I favour “... an, at best fitful, transition ...”, and would retain the pronunciation rule.